# Where can I find the Corda quickstart demos?

Tags: corda

The link from the white paper no longer works: https://www.corda.net/samples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.corda.net is currently being redesigned and the samples page is not currently available. You can temporarily find it here: http://www.corda.net/develop/samples.html.